# Unity-Android Plugin (Black Screen)

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm making a unity plugin for android. When I run my application on native, it runs perfectly. But when i call the same function from unity, it makes the background black and unity scene (by default in blue colour) doesn't show. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1.you should put the xml layout file under eclipse project to Unity project
2.you should register the Activity in manifest, and the manifest should be put to Unity project too.
3.make sure your operation is in UIThread.